# Activation of `.vimrc` file

Tags: linux, vi

I have got a `.vimrc` file from one of my friends, however, `vim` ignores it. How can I make `vim` use `.vimrc`? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You have to put it in your home folder.

Comment: Where have you placed it?

Comment: I have replaced the old `.vimrc` file by the new one in my `home` folder. Unfortunately, there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open vim and type ":version" and hit Enter. You will get paths to your vimrc files. Make sure that your vimrc file is not overwritten by another one (with a higher priority). Please refer to [Open vimrc file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file).

EDIT: To see a home directory, type in vim `:echo $HOME`

Comment: $VIM equals '/usr/share/vim'. Should I change it? If the answer is yes, could you tell me how I could perform it?