# My .vimrc file is completely ignored

Tags: linux, vim

I have got a `.vimrc` file from one of my friends, however, `vim` ignores it. In an other topic ([Activation of `.vimrc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419595/activation-of-vimrc-file/39420584#39420584)) it has turned out that the value of the VIM variable may cause problem (/usr/share/vim instead of /home/tobias). Should I change this route for the other one? If the answer is yes, how can I carry out it? Thank you for the answer.

-- edit --

`$ vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled Oct 18 2008 09:05:15)
Included patches: 1-314
Compiled by buildd@excelsior.roeckx.be
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic
+emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path
+folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist`
 +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +menu
+mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme
-netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl +postscript +printer +profile
-python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent
-sniff +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static
-tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title -toolbar
+user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace
+wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -O2 -g -Wall
Linking: gcc   -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/local/lib -o vim       -lncurses -lselinux -lacl -lgpm
```

-- endedit --

Comment: That `.vimrc` should be in `$HOME`.

Comment: So, should I give `$VIM=/home/tobias`? How?

Comment: No, there's no reason whatsoever to change `$VIM`. `$HOME/.vimrc` should work with any properly built and installed Vim on any UNIX-like system. If it doesn't, add the full output of `$ vim --version` to your question and give us details on everything you did to customize Vim.

Comment: Ok, I add the output, but, the admin will quickly remove it, therefore, there is no too much time to store it in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My friend has "debugged" the `.vimrc` file: the "line colouring" command has been missed from it, according to which I thought, there was some problem with `.vimrc`.

Comment: Heads up for anyone else being as stupid as I am. If you do sudo vi myfile, the .vimrc of root is used. And your own .vimrc obviously is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your vimrc into `$HOME/.vimrc`. You can check whether it got sourced via `:scriptnames`. For troubleshooting, you can also temporarily add `:echomsg "hello"` in there. You don't need to mess with the `$VIM` variable. `:help initialization` has all the gruesome details, should you be interested.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my Ubuntu install only came with this tiny-vim thing installed. I solved the issue by running `sudo apt install vim-gtk3`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the neovim package which updates the vim alternatives:

Following the symlink of vim with `readlink -f  $(which vim)` leads to neovim.

Installing `vim-gtk3` overrides the alternatives installed by neovim. This indeed fixes the issue but I don't actually want to install gvim nor the gtk libraries on my system.

Two solutions actually fix the problem:

1. Remove `neovim` which reverts the alternatives to `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`
2. Update the alternatives with `sudo update-alternatives --config vim`